# How to make all online android app users visible on map like in Periscope?

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, geofire

I've been on this for weeks and cannot seem to figure it out yet. Please help.

I'm using `Google Maps` API to create an app and I have succeeded in getting the `map` running. But I still need help with the following:

How do I make all online app users `visible` (to each other) on the `map` (like in Periscope)?

Comment: The google maps api uses markers to identify locations on a map.  That is clear in the api documentation.  In terms of updating for all users to see, you will need to figure out how you're storing and rendering user location data.  We would need a lot more information to help guide you in any type of implementation.  But if you want to experiment feel free to check out firebase (database as a service, and one of many possible solutions), it is great for handling realtime updates, and I would suggest reading through the api documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. There are many phases to what I am trying to achieve with the app, but I am taking it one step at a time to avoid asking an ambiguous question. For now what I'm trying to achieve is make online users visible to each other on map just like in Periscope. I've checked the documentation and didn't find it (or maybe I'm not just sure what to look for). I'll check out the firebase you recommended. More help please.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers is the link to markers.  The first code sample on how to add a marker should be pretty straight forward.  You will of course need to have the google maps API loaded before trying to add maps/markers.  Hopefully that helps.  If not, I would suggest investing a little time on a javascript tutorial which will make your life much easier.  Best of luck.

Comment: @user2263572 Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it. I had previously succeeded in adding markers using Java and I don't see the need to trying do it using JavaScript. My challenge is on how to make all my online users visible to each other and I just went through the documentation as you advised but didn't find anything to help me achieve that.

Comment: I would suggest reading up on a MVC type framework and then narrowing down your question.  If you are able to draw markers, your next step is figuring out a way to store user location data and having it render in a view when appropriate.  As I mentioned a database like Firebase would be especially good for something like this since you will probably constantly want your view updated when there are changes in your model.  Best of luck.

Comment: I've done some research on MVC, Traccar and Firebase. With the little knowledge I gathered, Firebase seems like the most appropriate for what I am trying to achieve. I'm still open to further suggestions.

Comment: @Emzor Did you find the solution for your problem. I would love to have insight in algorithm that you have implemented. If you don't mind sharing that.

Comment: @rptwsthi Not yet, still hacking my way through this one. Do share with me if you have any insight. Thanks.

Comment: @Emzor you can save all the online user's location coordinates in `Firebase` and then retrieve them in an `ArrayList<>()` and show all the markers on the map using a `for` loop. I think I'm too late and you already have figure out a way. Have you?